# iPad Splitview template and modal views

Tags: ipad, modal-dialog, uisplitviewcontroller

I am trying to do a modal view inside the SplitView template.

I can make one, but if you turn the device or just press on the modal view, it dissapears behind everything.

How can I make a full screen modal view ?  I have tried every modal style but the modal view will never stick around.

Comment: Does no one know how to make a modal view that keeps even if you rotate the device ?

Comment: You should post some sample code here to show more details about your problem. Otherwise we cannot help you. How are you displaying the modal view? Starting from what controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[urmodalviewcontroller setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];
```

or

```
urmodalviewcontroller.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
```